# Does long term storage pricing apply to data from GA daily export?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm wondering if anyone knows whether the long-term-storage pricing (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#long-term-storage) applies to GA daily export (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) data in BigQuery?

Since these tables cannot be modified, does it mean there will always be a discount 90 days after a daily GA table is available in BigQuery?

Comment: looks like you answered your question! Yes. there will be long term storage pricing applied after 90 days :o) What other scenario you see?

Answer (score 2):

As Mikhail said in a comment, the answer is yes: The long term storage discount will be applied on the GA tables, as in any other unchanged table you store in BigQuery for more than 90 days (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#long-term-storage).